# Pygame function error

Tags: python, function, class, pygame

I'm making this game with my friend for some fun, and I am trying to make a random amount of enemies to spawn and follow the player, but here is what happens:

**My main script**:

```
#set up
import pygame, sys, random, time, math
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()

#variables start----------------------------------
niass = "grass_shit.png" #grass image
mil = "head.png" #player name
ali = "head_2.png" #alien image

x, y = 0, 0 #character position
movex, movey = 0, 0 #how far the character will move
#x is left and right, y is up and down

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((850, 640),0,32) #set screen                       
background = pygame.image.load(niass).convert() #load image to screen

#WE NEED TO MAKE THESE IMAGERS RECTS BEFORE WE CAN MOVE ON
char = pygame.image.load(mil).convert_alpha() #covert player image
ali = pygame.image.load(ali).convert_alpha() #covert alien image

stop = random.randint(1,4)

#variables end------------------------------------

#classes------------------------------------------
class Enemys():
    def enemy():
        z, w = random.randint(10, 480), random.randint(10, 500)
        movez, movew = 0, 0

        if z < x:
            movez =+ 0.20
        elif z > x:
            movez =- 0.20
        if w < y:
            movew =+ 0.20
        elif w > y:
            movew =- 0.20

        w += movew
        z += movez

        screen.blit(ali,(z,w))

#classes------------------------------------------

while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type==QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
    if event.type==KEYDOWN:    
            if event.key==K_a:
                    movex=-1
            elif event.key==K_d:
                    movex=+1
            elif event.key==K_w:
                    movey=-1
            elif event.key==K_s:
                    movey=+1
    if event.type==KEYUP:
            if event.key==K_a:
                    movex=0
            elif event.key==K_d:
                    movex=0
            elif event.key==K_w:
                    movey=0
            elif event.key==K_s:
                    movey=0

    while stop > 0:
        stop =- 1
        Enemys.enemy()              

    x += movex
    y += movey

    screen.blit(background,(0,0))
    screen.blit(char,(x,y))
    pygame.display.update()
```

So, stop is the variable, picks a random number, and then in the while True part there is another while loop, which continues until stop is less the 0, and in the while loop the enemy function is run, but it's not liking it.

**Here's the error**:

```
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/claude/Dropbox/BigKahunaBurger/BigKahunaBurger LOOP.py", line 115, in <module>
    Enemys.enemy()
TypeError: unbound method enemy() must be called with Enemys instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
>>>
```

Comment: This code shows a lack of understanding what classes (and OO principles in general) are used for.

Comment: well obviasly i have a lack of understanding for classes thats why im asking for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two critical problems with the class and how you are using it. You should be declaring what is called an instance of your class such as `badGuy = Enemy()`. In the definition of `class Enemy()` you should have member functions with a parameter called `self` (or whatever you want to call it, as long as it is consistent), here is an example:

```
class Enemy():
    def __init__(self): # self is needed for all methods defined in Enemy
        # set some values that each unique enemy has, like health.
        self.health = 100
        self.damage = 10
    def attack(self, target):
        target.health -= self.damage # when inside the class, use self
```

Now outside of the class, you need to create some enemies:

```
bandit = Enemy()
robber = Enemy()
bandit.attack(robber)
print bandit.health, robber.health # outside the class use the variable name
# bandit is the object's name, enemy is the object's type.
```

Now that you see how useful classes are, go and learn all you can about them!

Comment: ok, so when I am creating the z and w position should i use self for that or not?

Comment: @VincentVega On the contrary, this is not helping you it is only meant to show you what you could easily learn with a little dedication to learning. Don't go off now expecting to write your own classes with no effort, go now and read a free book on Python, [here is a good start](http://inventwithpython.com/)